# Sony Vaio getting an “Operating System Not Found” screen and won’t boot up

Tags: windows, bios, ubuntu-20.04

Today I shutdown my laptop at afternoon through the OS shutdown option and now at the evening when I turned on it there was a “Operating System Not Found” message with whole black screen with white letters.

My PC is a Sony Vaio SVE14A15FBB with dual boot: Windows 7 as first OS and Linux Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa as secondary OS.

In order to fix this issue, I took my HD out, cleaned the connection port of it and attached it again at the PC but it didn’t work.

After that, I have tried another method, this time I changed the BIOS option from UEFI to legacy but again the error continued.

I also tried to repair the OS with the factory disks, I inserted the first CD and clicked in “Repair Windows 7” but it showed that my OS could be repaired.

This same issue already occurred with me more or less 4 times, but I always solved it by formatting entirely using the disks that came with the laptop, but everything was deleted.

I suspect that my HD doesn’t have any failure, I ran at the VAIO Care Rescue an individual HD test and it was displayed 0 failures in the two partitions, I have ran a check at the two partitions to verify the state of them and again they were able to be verified, now I am using the Ubuntu 20.04 at the “Try” mode.

Comment: what bootloader were you using? did you run a HD diagnostic from the BIOS?

Comment: What am I supposed to do to know the bootloader that I'm using?! I have no idea which is the one that I'm using... About the HD diagnostic I have tried to insert the factory disk to run a Windows 7 repair (my primary OS) but when the Starting Windows screen appears it looks like that the screen freezes, only when I'm gonna put the Ubuntu bootable USB pendrive I don't face issues

Comment: If you can run from a Live Ubuntu USB drive, but not from your HDD, likely there is disk damage, or bootloader damage. In that case, you should try to salvage all the contents of the HDD by making an image while running from USB drive, then as before, reinstall all. Heaving a **working** disk image should enable you to recover from this issue in the future.

Comment: I finish now to run a HD individual test and it gave me as results OK in everything (linear search, random search, funnel search and surface sweeping) and that there aren't errors detected in the HDD and at the PC... After I ran an HD check with error cleaning and the Vaio Care Rescue displayed that there aren't more errors and it was possible to see the size of each partition and the whole HD... Now I turned from Uefi to Legacy and it displayed another message instead OS not Found that is: bootmgr missing press ctrl+alt+del

Comment: @golimar Aptio Setup Utility - American Megatrends, Inc. 2011 and I finished now to run the HD diagnostic, it appeared that there aren't errors

Comment: Even with lots of tests and lack of issues in HD the problem persists on, I think that the issue is in the OS but I think that I'm gonna to format unfortunately

Comment: If the OS isn't found then the OS isn't the problem. There are three possibilities: the hard drive, the boot loader, or the BIOS.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik is the way to go in my opinion, and also while running that live Linux you could try to reinstall GRUB on the HD. That could possibly autodetect your Windows+Linux installations and create boot entries for both

Comment: @music2myear But I don't know how the hard drive could be a problem if it was tested through the Vaio Care Rescue and it gave OK in all tests, also, when I applied an individual test at the hard drive here it appeared that there isn't failures in my hard drive. About the BIOS and the boot loader it would be impossible to discover which of those are with problem